# By group, sort and assign total to highest ranking item and 0 to rest

Tags: r, gis

I aim to map Metropolitan Statistical Areas (MSAs or CBSAs) and their population over a base map of U.S. counties. MSA counties will be shaded and non-MSA counties left blank (basic choropleth map). MSA total populations will be represented by proportional circles centered on the respective MSAs' largest counties by population. I am processing the underlying data and have hit a hurdle.

The data is in a df with over 1000 rows, of which this sample:

```
head(pop_2010_map[order(pop_2010_map$cbsa_code),], 5)
    cbsa_code cbsa_name county_code_long Population
936     10180   Abilene            48059      13544
967     10180   Abilene            48253      20202
993     10180   Abilene            48441     131506
765     10420     Akron            39133     161419
768     10420     Akron            39153     541781
```

I need to aggregate population by cbsa_code and assign the total to the biggest (highest population) county_code_long and 0 to the remaining county_code_long within each cbsa_code.

The expected result should look like this:

```
    cbsa_code cbsa_name county_code_long Population
936     10180   Abilene            48059          0
967     10180   Abilene            48253          0
993     10180   Abilene            48441     165252
765     10420     Akron            39133          0
768     10420     Akron            39153     703200
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `dplyr`'s functions `group_by()` and `mutate()` with an `ifelse` statement, as follows:

```
# Load library
library(dplyr)

# Create example data.frame
x <- read.table(text = 
"cbsa_code cbsa_name county_code_long Population
936     10180   Abilene            48059      13544
967     10180   Abilene            48253      20202
993     10180   Abilene            48441     131506
765     10420     Akron            39133     161419
768     10420     Akron            39153     541781")

# Desired result
new_x <- x %>% 
  group_by(cbsa_code) %>% 
  mutate(Population = ifelse(Population == max(Population), 
                             sum(Population), 0)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

And the result looks like:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  cbsa_code cbsa_name county_code_long Population
      <int>    <fctr>            <int>      <dbl>
1     10180   Abilene            48059          0
2     10180   Abilene            48253          0
3     10180   Abilene            48441     165252
4     10420     Akron            39133          0
5     10420     Akron            39153     703200
```

**Update:**

Let's say there's two counties with a tie, both with maximum population (I just added an example for Akron):

```
# Create example data.frame
y <- read.table(text = 
                  "cbsa_code cbsa_name county_code_long Population
936     10180   Abilene            48059      13544
967     10180   Abilene            48253      20202
993     10180   Abilene            48441     131506
765     10420     Akron            39133     161419
768     10420     Akron            39153     541781
769     10420     Akron            39154     541781")
```

In this case, if we apply the code above...

```
y %>% 
  group_by(cbsa_code) %>% 
  mutate(Population = ifelse(Population == max(Population), 
                             sum(Population), 0)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

... we get two entries for "Akron" county

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  cbsa_code cbsa_name county_code_long Population
      <int>    <fctr>            <int>      <dbl>
1     10180   Abilene            48059          0
2     10180   Abilene            48253          0
3     10180   Abilene            48441     165252
4     10420     Akron            39133          0
5     10420     Akron            39153    1244981
6     10420     Akron            39154    1244981
```

If you want the full table with the zeros, here's a solution (see 
[this dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html) 
for more information about the approach):

```
# Rank the Population values according to their descending order, so that the 
## one with maximum is ranked 1 (if there are ties, only one of them is chosen).
y %>% 
  group_by(cbsa_code) %>% 
  mutate(pop_rank = row_number(desc(Population)),
         Population = ifelse(pop_rank == 1, 
                             sum(Population), 0)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-pop_rank)
```

Resulting in:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  cbsa_code cbsa_name county_code_long Population
      <int>    <fctr>            <int>      <dbl>
1     10180   Abilene            48059          0
2     10180   Abilene            48253          0
3     10180   Abilene            48441     165252
4     10420     Akron            39133          0
5     10420     Akron            39153    1244981
6     10420     Akron            39154          0
```

If you only want to keep the counties with maximum populaton, you could use 
`summarise()` like so (arbitrarily taking the first `county_code_long`):

```
y %>% 
  group_by(cbsa_code, cbsa_name) %>% 
  summarise(Population = sum(Population), 
            county_code_long = county_code_long[1]) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Resulting in:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  cbsa_code cbsa_name Population county_code_long
      <int>    <fctr>      <int>            <int>
1     10180   Abilene     165252            48059
2     10420     Akron    1244981            39133
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I need to assign the _group total of population_ to the item with the _highest population of the group_. I believe what you have done is just assign 0 to the non-top ranking codes. I've tweaked your code and I think this works: `new_x <- x %>% 
  group_by(cbsa_code) %>% 
  mutate(Population = ifelse(Population == max(Population), sum(Population), 0)) %>% 
  ungroup()`

Comment: @syre Sorry, you're absolutely right! I've corrected the answer. Also, just an aside that if you're actually not interested in keeping the other `county_code_long`, you could do `x %>% group_by(cbsa_code, cbsa_name) %>% summarise(Population = sum(Population), county_code_long = max(county_code_long)) %>% ungroup()`.

Comment: @syre also note that if you have more than one `max(county_code_long)` per `cbsa_code`, you're actually going to get more than one result per `cbsa_code`. I think one way to ensure you only have one result per `cbsa_code` would be to add `distinct()` at the end of the pipe of commands.

Comment: I'm not trying to rank `county_code_long` (which is an id code) but `Population` so your code is still off by a bit. See my solution. And you're right, we should avoid ties so please add `distinct()`. I would do it myself if I knew where to put it exactly.

Comment: @syre Sorry again! I hope I got it right this time... I've amended it and also expanded the answer to deal with possible ties in the maximum population (the `distinct()` idea didn't quite work after all!). I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
 x <- read.table(text = 
              "cbsa_code cbsa_name county_code_long Population
            936     10180   Abilene            48059      13544
            967     10180   Abilene            48253      20202
            993     10180   Abilene            48441     131506
            765     10420     Akron            39133     161419
            768     10420     Akron            39153     541781")
```

Using simple base function. (I have simplified it, thus is not for general problem)

```
   a=mapply(tapply,list(x$Population),list(x$cbsa_code),c(sum,which.max))
   x$Population=0;x$Population[cumsum(a[,2])]=a[,1]
   x
              cbsa_code cbsa_name county_code_long  Population
  936            10180    Abilene            48059          0
  967            10180    Abilene            48253          0
  993            10180    Abilene            48441     165252
  765            10420      Akron            39133          0
  768            10420      Akron            39153     703200
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for my larger dataset. For example, some groups end up with 0s all around, while other groups end up with multiple non-0 figures.

Comment: actually I warned you before I wrote it ... I over simplified it.. just giving you the idea of how to go about it. maybe I can try and write a general format code

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind offer, but I've already got a solution in my comment to the first answer, so don't waste too much of your time on this.